# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {texto})

Tags: reactjs

React beginner problem. Is there any tutorial or guide to check before asking here?

I'm learning by my own React JS and following:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/aprende-react-desde-cero-curso-de-react-con-proyectos/
Sorry, if it's an easy problem, but i'm stuck.
I'm getting this error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {texto}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"
Any advice is welcome.

**App.jsx**

```
import './App.css';
import Tarea from './componentes/Tarea';
import frog from './img/frog.png'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="aplicacion-tareas">
      <div className='logo-contenedor'>
        
        <img 
        src={ frog } alt='rana'
        className='logo'  />

      </div>
      <div className='lista-tareas-principal'>
        <h1>Mis tareas</h1>
        <Tarea texto='Aprender React'  />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Tarea.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/tarea.css'


function Tarea (texto) {
  return (
    <div className='tarea-contenedor'> 
        <div className='tarea-texo'> 
            {texto}
        </div> 
        <div className='tarea-icono'>
            Eliminar
        </div>   
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tarea
```

I'm using snippet in Visual Studio Code, so I'm trying to use "rafce" and variations and I'm not sure what is wrong in my code. As I told any advice to follow a tutorial or anything to improve is welcome.

Comment: Before asking you could just try to search for the error you get.

Comment: Thank you, I tried searching and I was getting a complex solution. And I knew it should be something really easy. I wil check better next time. Thanks in advance for every advice.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that, you're trying to render an object. So, your `texto` seems like an object. Because you're getting the props wrong.

Change this

```
function Tarea (texto)
```

To this

```
function Tarea ({texto})
```